# Using QR decomposition to find an orthonormal basis of a polynomial vector space

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, change-of-basis, gram-schmidt

I am doing the following exercise:

> Let $P_{5}$ be the vector space of real polynomials with degree at most 5. Identify this space with the usual isomorphism on $\mathbb{R}^6$:
>
> $$T\left( \displaystyle \sum_{i=0}^{5} a_{i}x^{i}\right) = (a_{0},a_{1}, \ldots, a_{5})$$
>
> a) Find the symmetric matrix $A$ such that the inner product in $\mathbb{R}^6$, defined by $$\langle u, v \rangle = v^{T} \cdot A \cdot u$$ represents the inner product in $P_{5}$:
>
> $$\displaystyle \langle u, v \rangle_{P} = \int_{-1}^{1} u(x)v(x) dx$$
>
> b) Let $V$ be an orthonormal basis of eigenvectors of $A$ and $D$ the diagonal matrix with the eigenvalues of $A$. Define the basis $U = V \cdot D^{-1/2}$. Show that, on this basis, the inner product defined in a) is the usual inner product on the cannonical basis.
>
> c) Use the QR decomposition of any software to find the orthonormal polynomials resulting from the Gram-Schmidt process applied to the basis $B = [1,x,x^2, \ldots, x^5]$. (Hint: use letter b)

Ok, a), and b) are easy. For a), one can compute the matrix by $a_{ij} = \langle e_{i},e_{j} \rangle_{P}$, where $e_{i} = x^{i-1}$, for $i = 1, \ldots 6$.

For b), just write $u$ in the cannonical basis $E$ as $u_{E} = U \cdot u_{U}$ where $u_{U}$ is the vector $u_{E}$ represented on the basis $U$. Therefore, computing $u_{E}^{T} \cdot A \cdot v_{E}$ gives the desired result.

I am struggling with letter c). My idea is: I write the vectors $e_{i}$ (which represents the basis $B$) of $\mathbb{R}^6$ on the basis $U$ and apply the QR decomposition on the matrix T which has on its colums the vectors $e_{i}$ on the basis $U$. Therefore, as a result, the matrix $Q$ will be an orthogonal matrix where its columns are orthonormal vectors represented on the basis $U$, then I return each vector to the cannonical basis and get the desired result. Is this right? It does not seem right to me, I think maybe I am misinterpretating the question.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legendre_polynomials

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your interpretation sounds correct. The Graham-Schmidt process orthogonalizes a set of vectors with respect to the usual inner product, $\langle u, v \rangle = v^Tu$. If $u,v$ are written with respect to the basis $U$, then that inner product is equivalent to $\langle u_E, v_E \rangle_A := v_E^T \cdot A \cdot u_E$, which you have already shown corresponds to the standard inner product on $P_5$. So you want to take your basis $B$ for $P_5$, find the corresponding set of vectors of $\mathbb{R}^6$ via the canonical isomorphism, represent those vectors in base $U$, orthogonalize via Graham-Schmidt to get some vectors (still in base U), represent them in the canonical basis, and then find the corresponding polynomials, which will be an orthonormal basis for $P_5$.